# Multi Item Carousel slider: horizontal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I worked on a bootstrap Multi Item carousel slider and used some code from internet. But the code doesn't work correctly. The problem is that the cards doesn't show horizontal next to each other. And I have no idea how to solve that problem

https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/temp/819683?action=prism_export I used this link for it, but it doesn't work how it should.

It now looks like this [image]

Comment: Check the below snippet for Bootstrap 4 carousel which has cards.

Comment: Make sure you have included the bootstrap library (css & js) files onto your project. The include stack should look like this: `bootstrap -> your_custom_css -> more custom`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below snippet for bootstrap carousel with cards

```js
$('#recipeCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 10000
})

$('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function() {
  var minPerSlide = 3;
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i = 0; i < minPerSlide; i++) {
    next = next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item>div {
    display: none;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item>div:first-child {
    display: block;
  }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
}


/* display 3 */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
    transform: translateX(33.333%);
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    transform: translateX(-33.333%);
  }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container text-center my-3">
    <h2 class="font-weight-light">Bootstrap 4 - Multi Item Carousel</h2>
    <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
      <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card card-body">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/280x350?text=1">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card card-body">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/280x350?text=2">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card card-body">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/280x350?text=3">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card card-body">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/280x350?text=4">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card card-body">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/280x350?text=5">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card card-body">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/280x350?text=6">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```